# DataGridView is not able to populate by LINQ to SQL object

Tags: c#, sql, linq, datagridview

I'm trying to populate a `DataGridView` on my `WinForms` application (`dgvOrderSizes`) using the code below. As commented in code, if I assign `cod` to my `DataGridView` it populates fine but when I try to assign `orderDetails` to it, it doesn't get populated. I tried debugging the code and found that `DataSource` property is assigned properly, so I wonder why the grid doesn't get populated? (There are no Exceptions raised)

```
    protected void ShowOrderDetails(int orderNo)
    {

        this.dgvOrderSizes.DataSource = null;

        var cod = from orderDetail in db.OrderDetails
                                 where orderDetail.OrderNo == orderNo
                                 select orderDetail;

        //this.dgvOrderSizes.DataSource = cod;        //works until here


        var orderDetails = from pOrder in cod.AsEnumerable()
                                 select new { pOrder.Plies, pOrder.Composition, pOrder.Size, pOrder.UnitName, pOrder.Quantity, pOrder.Rate, pOrder.ProductionUnitName, pOrder.DeliveryUnitName };

        this.dgvOrderSizes.DataSource = orderDetails;       //doesn't work
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DataGridView uses a quite astonishing number of APIs, including IListSource, IList, ITypedList, IBindingList, IBindingListView, and most of CompnentModel (including all the descriptor stuff), and a rage more. If you say it works with "cod" then presumably LINQ-to-SQL is providing at least one of those APIs, and LINQ-to-Objects is not (which is fine; itisn't required to).

Just call ToList() and all will work:

```
blah.DataSource = orderDetails.ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks Marc, it works perfectly.But I'm still curious why LINQ-to-Objects wont support at least one of all these interfaces?

Comment: @UIS because it aims to provide non-buffered iterator-block method; you can't get Length on such a device, so IList is impossible